# Apache password-protected folder disappears --> Problem with mod_auth_basic and mod_authn_file

Tags: linux, apache, server, module

I've tried to password-protect the directory "www.example.com/bla" on my apache server using mod_auth_basic and mod_authn_file.
in my httpd.conf I added:

```
<Location "/bla">
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "private area"
        AuthBasicProvider file
        AuthUserFile /home/passwords/password-file
        Require valid-user
</Location>
```

As soon as I restarted the apache, I can't see the folder bla on example.com (= on the parent-folder, where it is located). It's not deleted though, I just can't see it on my page. The password protection also works perfectly fine when I access bla directly via example.com/bla.
So somehow my server seems to hide all the directories that are password protected. How can I change that?

Comment: Look for `Options +Indexes FollowSymLinks` to enable directory indices.

Comment: Hi, it's already enabled with `Options Indexes FollowSymLinks` .. so that's probably not it! :)

Answer (score 0):

For the parent (non-protected) folder use the following directive:

IndexOptions ShowForbidden